# How to manage Multiple Network Calls at a time in UITabbarController?

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

- I have five **Tabs** in **Tabbar** and on each tab's screen i have a network call to hit.
- I don't want to cancel any network call on switch of tab.
- All five network calls should be processed parallel at a time.
- Response of all calls should be populated on their screen whenever network layer send response.

  **Note: I have only one Network Class to manage all network calls.**

Comment: Why don't you keep respective call in their own `UI`? Without knowing the `TabBarController` setup, To make calls at once, use the custom class for `TabBarController` but then you have to pass your models to respective child controllers.

Comment: All calls are in their respective screens(UIViewController)/ child controllers.

Comment: Not sure if this is the case with programmatically created `TabBarController` but if you have setup your `TabBarController` via `storyboard` then each child `viewController` will initialize on the tap of the respective tab hence the API call will happen after that.

Comment: I think there is misunderstanding in discussion regrading my question. Actually I have designed everything through storyboard. Only need to populate data on each screens which i will get from API calls just like profile screen. My question was how i will manage multiple API calls with single Network class at a time as i know i have option to switch tab anytime.

Comment: i am not using storyboard, and i tired to call it on viewWillAppear. But for some reason viewWillAppear will be called on creation